# Applying Raoult's Law in volatile solids–liquid solutions

Tags: thermodynamics, solutions, vapor-pressure

My textbook explains applying Raoult's Law for the two cases:

1. liquid–liquid solutions, in which the vapour pressure of the solution is due to both the components
2. non-volatile solids–liquid solutions, in which the vapour pressure of the solution is only due to the liquid component of the solution

I am curious as to what will happen (how things change for the application of Raoult's Law) if the solution consisted of some volatile solid like camphor, in some liquid (possibly some liquid hydrocarbon).

Certainly, the solid now also contribute to the total vapour pressure of the solution, but does it still block the escaping of the solvent molecules into vapour phase as much as the non-volatile solid blocks the liquid solvent molecules?

If yes, then how can I apply Raoult's Law for the case to find the total pressure of the solution?

Answer (score -1):

Raoult's Law is only valid when the solute is non-volatile. Therefore, you cannot apply it.